# Self-hosted wiki with strong search (including OCR)

Tags: ocr, self-hosted, wiki, knowledge-base

I'm looking for a wiki software that:

**Must have:**

1. Strong search capabilities (include search text on images)
2. Paste images directly from clipboard (no need for intermediate file)
3. Must not require internet access (nor send off information to remote server)
4. Self-hosted (Can be accessed by multiple machines from LAN)

**Nice to have:**

1. Tagging (add a bunch of tags to a topic and filter / browse per tag)
2. book-like organization (like evernote/onenote: categories, sections, sub-sections)
3. Easy to upgrade
4. Support for Markdown

**Trying to solve:**

Create a knowledge base for a team of 2-5 people.

NOTE: I already tested ZimWiki and TiddyWiki and they don't meet reqs 1 and 2.

Comment: I am not sure "Paste images directly from clipboard" is doable with web technologies... do you know any other website that has this feature, so that I can investigate it? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I know tagspaces can do it but they are not exactly "wiki" (and it doesn't search images). I believe it runs on a self-contained webkit.

Comment: Also this one seem to do it: http://pasteboard.co/

Comment: That works indeed! I just learnt something new, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), open source wiki package, originally for use on Wikipedia.

Also, you can look at [XWiki](http://www.xwiki.org/). This one has extensions support so you can expand its functionality as you want.

Comment: Could you give a reason or details why you recommend this software? Since the user who ask the recommendation has requirements what software he is looking for.

Comment: I've already tried `XWiki` it doesn't allow pasting an image straight in the editor and it also doesn't OCR the image to make it searchable... I'll try MediaWiki to see.

Comment: Ok, I just tried `MediaWiki` and it has the same short comings as `XWiki` (don't meet my reqs number 1 and 2)

Comment: Why do you want to paste images? You want to copy images from the web and don't host them? Then you can try drag and drop images into visual editor. Or you want to copy paste images from your PC?

Comment: I deal with a lot of diagrams and I don't want to have to make multiple uploads before I can write an entry. I know that will make it cumbersome enough for the people in the team not to use the software.

Comment: You can find Media folder on your self hosted Wiki directory and put all your diagrams there. You don't need to upload every image throughout post editor.

Comment: This is what I would suggest too.

Comment: well, that only if the person doing the editing have the access to the server file system... which won't be everyone. Besides that point it still can't search the images either.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after testing several different wiki software (and even some note taking software with collaboration) we decided to go with a tiny self-hosted wiki called [BookStackApp](https://www.bookstackapp.com).  Meets all my requirements except the OCR.

[image: BookStackApp]

Big decision factor is that it's open source so I can contribute with patches and features when I can/have time. Plus it uses lavarel PHP framework so it is actually possible to integrate with TerassectOCR ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447245/using-tesseractocr-in-laravel#34646673)) without changing it's basic structure/architecture.

Comment: I'm back to looking for alternatives again

Comment: You say you're looking for alternatives again (or were a year-and-a-half ago).  What shortcomings did you find in BookStack?